# Correct way to calculate time to an event variable

Tags: survival, cox-model

Is this the correct way to calculate time to an event(death) for survival analysis?

t2death column calculated using SQL as:

```
case when death_dt is not null 
then death_dt - admission_dt else study_end_dt - admission_dt end as t2death
```

The final data looks like:

```
id  time0       study_end_dt    admission_dt    death_dt        t2death
1   2021-05-24  2022-08-31      2021-05-24      NA              464
2   2019-12-10  2022-08-31      2020-01-19      2020-01-23      4
3   2020-10-14  2022-08-31      2020-11-22      2020-12-03      11
4   2021-11-23  2022-08-31      2021-11-26      NA              278
```

My concern is that there is t2death value for id: 1, 4, but they are still alive.

1. How does a survival analysis algorithm know that they have been
   censored?
2. Any reading resources or explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explicitly show us your calculation?  All the date differences do look correct.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, whuber. I have updated my post.

Comment: Wouldn't the answer depend on what your software expects?  There are different conventions for indicating which data have been censored.  I suspect you can find the answer by consulting your software's documentation.  Running any examples that come with it can be helpful.

Comment: Do you have specific survival software in mind? The R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) is a good choice. It comes with many helpful vignettes to explain its use in different circumstances, and is the basis for a few thousand questions with answers on this site.

Answer (score 0):

For question 1: Software expects an indicator variable to distinguish time values that represent events from those that represent censoring. The coding depends on the software. In R for this type of data, 0 is typically used for censored and 1 for an event. In contrast, at one time at least, Matlab used opposite coding; that led to some interesting conversations with a colleague until we figured out that difference. That coding can be extended to allow for multiple types of state transitions.

For question 2: The vignettes of the R [`survival` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=survival) can be very helpful. The main vignette, "The survival package," is a good overview. Other vignettes go into detail about specific aspects of survival analysis. This Cross Validated site has some
[Book suggestions for survival analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/534450/28500) and about 2000 pages to date on the topic.